# Is there a way to make std::set_terminate accept a function that is inside a class?

Tags: c++, c++11, exception

so I am trying to create a crash logging system that would allow a user to add a message through a function `addMessage(const char* message)` and if he chooses he can allow the crash logger to handle any exception that is thrown in the program by calling a `allowGlobalErrorCatching()` function.

The thing is that **both of these functions** are inside a **class** and what I have done inside `allowGlobalErrorCatching()` function is I added `std::set_terminate()`, but when I try to pass a function from a class the compiler gives me an error of

> E0167 Argument of type "void(ProcessLogger::*)()" is incompatible with
>   parameter of type "terminate_handler"

So is there any way to make it accept a class function or do I have to make a global one?

Comment: You need to make that class member function `static`.

Comment: That's not possible. How will the compiler know *on which class instance* to call your member function? You indeed have to make it static or a free function.

Comment: @TheDude making the function static fixes the problem. Thanks!

Comment: But it also means your class will have to be a singleton, So the whole thing is a bit unpleasant.

Comment: Or alternatively have some global/static variable that allows you access the instance of the class from which you want to call that method (then a static/free function that does the job of calling that method for you). Maybe you'd be interested in a singleton design pattern ?

Comment: @StoryTeller An interned singleton with an interface like `someOtherLogListener`  would do. No need for a _real_ singleton.

Comment: @Caninonos the goal was to allow the class to have only one instance and was thinking how to do that turns out a single ton is what that is :) so I can hit two birds with one stone